# LBW to a Spinners Full Toss

Tags: cricket

So, a spinner bowls a full toss.  The batsman plays a shot, but misses it.  The ball hits the batsman, on his crease and below shoulder height, so is definitely not a no-ball.  It hits the batsman inline with the stumps (somewhere between the outside of off and the outside of leg stumps).  However, it hits him about the height of the stumps.  The ball is clearly dipping and will be below bail height by the time it would otherwise get to the stumps.

Question, is this LBW or does this count as being hit outside the line of the stumps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would count as LBW above the stumps but in line wicket to wicket is acceptable.

The height is only used to judge whether the ball is hitting the stumps.

See [36.1.d](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-36-leg-before-wicket/) which directly addresses this.